# Is it possible to access NativeWifi api for hostedNetwork on WIndows using C# not C++

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, wlanapi

[The reference page for hosted network and ICS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815252(v=vs.85).aspx) links to references that are written in C++. Can I skip C++ and use C# and a Windows forms application?

Comment: [COM Interop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Interop).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Native Wifi is implemented (its client side at least) mostly inside `wlanapi.dll` library, so you just need to import necessary functions from there.